# Srtange result from mysql function

Tags: mysql

I create a function that returns a value, selected in a periods table like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE `periods` (
  `period` DATE NOT NULL,
  `threshold` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`period`)
 )
 COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
 ENGINE=InnoDB;

+------------------------+
|        periods         |
+------------+-----------+
|   period   | threshold |
+------------+-----------+
| 2013-11-01 |     5     |
+------------+-----------+
| 2013-12-01 |     1     |
+------------+-----------+
| 2014-01-01 |     5     |
+------------+-----------+
| 2014-02-01 |     5     |
+------------+-----------+
```

And function create:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GET_THRESHOLD`(`PERIOD` VARCHAR(10))
 RETURNS double
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 READS SQL DATA
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT 'RETURN THRESHOLD'
 BEGIN
   DECLARE RESULT DOUBLE;
   SELECT threshold INTO RESULT FROM periods WHERE period = PERIOD LIMIT 1;
   RETURN RESULT;
 END
 $$
 DELIMITER ;
```

but the function returns a value the Wrong

```
mysql>SELECT GET_THRESHOLD('2013-12-01')
-> 5
```

someone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

You parameter has the same name as a column.  That's a no-no.  Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GET_THRESHOLD`(`V_PERIOD` VARCHAR(10))
 RETURNS double
 LANGUAGE SQL
 NOT DETERMINISTIC
 READS SQL DATA
 SQL SECURITY DEFINER
 COMMENT 'RETURN THRESHOLD'
 BEGIN
   DECLARE RESULT DOUBLE;
   SELECT threshold INTO RESULT FROM periods WHERE period = V_PERIOD LIMIT 1;
   RETURN RESULT;
 END
 $$
 DELIMITER
```

The statement:

```
WHERE period = PERIOD
```

is comparing the column value to itself.  So, it chooses all rows that have a non-NULL column value.  Not very interesting.

It is good practice to always prefix variables and arguments with something to distinguish them from columns in tables.